# Automatically ssh when starting konsole

Tags: ssh, console, kubuntu

I'm interested, is it possible to set up automatic ssh login when I start konsole on kubuntu.
To be more precise, when I start konsole I would like that it automatically  starts ssh and logins to remote computer.  On windows I would put this kind of options to "target" section on shorcut properties for putty.  Can't figure out how to do the same on linux with konsole.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into Documentation http://docs.kde.org/development/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html

I see you could create a profile, or create a tab using file

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a new Konsole Profiles and place in the command option something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@server
```

I'm assuming you use a no password configuration through an RSA key.